# Grok learning python programming

Tags: python

I am wondering how to solve this problem:

You are curious about the most popular and least popular colours of cars and decide to write a program to calculate the frequency of car colours.

Your program should read in the colour of each car until a blank line is entered, and then print out (in any order) all the different colours of car with counts.

For example:

```
Car: red
Car: white
Car: blue
Car: green
Car: white
Car: silver
Car: 
Cars that are green: 1
Cars that are silver: 1
Cars that are red: 1
Cars that are white: 2
Cars that are blue: 1
```

​
Here is another example:

```
Car: red
Car: white
Car: white
Car: red
Car: white
Car: white
Car: white
Car: 
Cars that are red: 2
Cars that are white: 5
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
cars = {}

line = input('Car: ')
while line:
  cars[line] = cars.get(line, 0) + 1
  line = input('Car: ')

for colour in cars:
  print('Cars that are ' + colour + ':', cars[colour])
```

This should help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `input` multiple times with a sentinel value, then count the objects, then iterate over the keys and values, and then print a formatted string for each count. Reasonably straightforward with one line of code:

```
print(*('Cars that are {}: {}'.format(*item) for item in __import__('collections').Counter(iter(lambda: input('Car: '), '')).items()), sep='\n')
```